# display text file change to another text file time to time in the same content

Tags: php, javascript, file, text, time

In my index.php my cotent has been displayed trough a text file called txt1. So everything that is on the txt1 that is located at the server is going to be displayed to the content index.php.
What I want to is in the content that will be displayed will not display just from one text file but i want every few second to change it to  another text file called txt2. So it will change to different content into the text box.

```
<div id="content">
    <br> 
    <font align="center" color="white" size="3"><b>
    <?php
                        $myFile = "txt1.txt";
                        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
                        $theData = fgets($fh);
                        fclose($fh);
                        echo $theData;
                    ?>  
    </b></font></div>
```

This is our i got the code, so is basically is just read what is on the text file. 
so how do i have to read different text file and change every second the text file in the same content.

I need this to be in JavaScript be use PHP. so JavaScript inside of PHP.

Comment: You'll need `setInterval` function that requests the text file every second. [Check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create two different divs.  One contains the data for txt1.txt.
The other contains the data for txt2.txt and is hidden.

```
<div class="content"><?=file_get_contents('txt1.txt')?></div>
<div class="content" style="display:none"><?=file_get_contents('txt2.txt')?></div>
```

Then, just use javascript to hide the first dive and show the other div.

```
//using Jquery
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var time=2; //Number of seconds
        setInterval(toggle_content, time*1000);
    })
    function  toggle_content() {
        $('.content').toggle()
    }
})
```