# .setInterval function that requests different text file into the same content

Tags: php, javascript, setinterval

```
<div id="content">
<br> 
<font align="center" color="white" size="3"><b>
<?php
    $myFile = "txt1.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
    $theData = fgets($fh);
    fclose($fh);
    echo $theData;
?>  
</b></font></div>
```

This is the code, so basically, I just want to read what is on the text file. so how do I have to read different text file and change every second the text file in the same content. so is basically in 30 sec seconds changes to txt2.

I need this to be in JavaScript be use PHP. so JavaScript inside of PHP.

Comment: JavaScript and PHP are two different languages.  You'd have to use AJAX to have JavaScript request the files from PHP.

Comment: you don't need the font tag.  It's making your page look real bad. You can control styling from a style sheet and setting an id or class around your content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [display text file change to another text file time to time in the same content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507261/display-text-file-change-to-another-text-file-time-to-time-in-the-same-content)

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents()` is better than fopen.

Save this script in a separate page, and use this:

This should be work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'pageYouCreated.php',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#content font b').html(data);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: how do i do it to change to a different text file?